# Most Efficient way to Combine Arrays removing Duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, react-native

Using a Flatlist and looking for an efficient way to combine elements of a list, while removing the duplicate elements. Each element has a unique key value, to know whether it is a duplicate or not.

My current implimentation uses the concat function:

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
      var a = this.concat();
      for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
          for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; ++j) {
              if(a[i].key === a[j].key)
                  a.splice(j--, 1);
          }
      }
      return a;
  };

const OldArray = this.state.data;
const NewArray = [] //contains values we loaded in 
const FinalArray = OldArray.concat(NewArray).unique();

//Update the State
this.setState({
   data: FinalArray
)}
```

This definitely works, but every time this function runs its at least N^2 efficiency, which seems bad. Is there a better way to do this? I feel like there must be..

Answer (score 3):

You can use Array#reduce to creae a Map of unique values, and then spread it back to an array. This will get you the 1st appearance of the objects that have the same key.

```js
const union = (arr1, arr2, key) => [... // spread to an array
  arr1.concat(arr2) // concat the arrays
  .reduce((m, o) => m.has(o[key]) ? m : m.set(o[key], o), new Map) // reduce to a map by value of key
  .values()]; // get the values iterator

const OldArray = [{ a: 1, v: 1 }, { a: 2 }]
const NewArray = [{ a: 1, v: 100 }, { a: 3 }]
const FinalArray = union(OldArray, NewArray, 'a')

console.log(FinalArray);
```

The other option, as suggested by @4castle, is to use Array#map to initialize the Map. However, this will take the last appearance of the objects that have the same key. You can always Array#reverse the array before initializing the Map.

```js
const union = (arr1, arr2, key) => [... // spread to an array
  new Map(arr1.concat(arr2).map(o => [o[key], o])) // concat and initialize the map
  .values()]; // get the values iterator

const OldArray = [{ a: 1, v: 1 }, { a: 2 }]
const NewArray = [{ a: 1, v: 100 }, { a: 3 }]
const FinalArray = union(OldArray, NewArray, 'a')

console.log(FinalArray);
```

Comment: `new Map(arr1.concat(arr2).map(o => [o[key], o]))` can also be used to create the `Map`.

Comment: Indeed. However, there is a little caveat. See updated answer.